# Does this type of "cyclic" matrix have a name?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\{a_1, a_2, ..., a_n\} \subset \mathbb{C}$ and consider the matrix of the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
  a_1 & a_2 & ... & a_{n-1} & a_n\\
  a_2 & a_3 & ... & a_n & a_1\\
  .\\
  .\\
  .\\
  a_n & a_1 & ... & a_{n-2} & a_{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Does this type of matrix have a specific name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is a type of [**Circulant Matrix**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix).

Comment: The wikipedia article you linked to says that the last row of a circulant matrix is the reverse of the first column which is not the case in the matrix above.

Comment: @Anfänger The *very next sentence* in the article says that different sources define circulant matrices differently. In particular, the direction of a shift is a common way circulant matrices can have different definitions. For example, in the article the first element is on the main diagonal; the OP's matrix has the last element along the anti-diagonal. But the matrix is still circulant when viewed as a set of cyclically permuted vectors of the first row/column.