# Can one figure out if a matrix is cyclic just by looking at its Jordan Normal Form?

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Can one figure out if a matrix is cyclic just by looking at its [Jordan Normal Form  ?](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form)

Comment: What is a cyclic matrix? Do you mean [circulant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1553662/does-this-type-of-cyclic-matrix-have-a-name)?

Comment: @DietrichBurde yes

Comment: The answer is no. A non-circulant matrix can be similar to a circulant matrix, but both matrices have the same Jordan forms due to similarity.

Comment: On the other hand, you can tell whether [$\Bbb C^n$ is $T$-cyclic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_subspace) by looking at the Jordan form.